# Complex table with cell/box inside cell

Tags: tables

I'm currently beginning to use LaTeX technology and stumbled upon this problem, I have read several tabular manuals on CTAN with no success.

I'm trying to create a table like this:

```
    +---------+--------+--------+--------+
    |     |114|    |100|    |92 |    |101|
    |     |___|    |___|    |___|    |___|
    |         |        |        |        |
    | 113     | 99     | 84     | 97     |
    +---------+--------+--------+--------+
    |     |114|    |100|    |92 |    |101|
    |     |___|    |___|    |___|    |___|
    |         |        |        |        |
    | 113     | 99     | 84     | 97     |
    +---------+--------+--------+--------+
    |     |114|    |100|    |92 |    |101|
    |     |___|    |___|    |___|    |___|
    |         |        |        |        |
    | 113     | 99     | 84     | 97     |
    +---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Is there any existing package to achieve this structure? If not, I was thinking about nesting rows or something like that, though I'm not sure yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A solution with Plain TeX for fun, learning, and to show what's possible with the basic building blocks:

```
\def\widest{000}
\def\uv{\unskip\vrule}
\def\bx#1#2{\vbox{%
  \offinterlineskip%
  \halign{\ \hfil## &##&\ \hfil## \cr
    \hphantom{\widest}&&\hphantom{\widest}\cr
    &\vrule\strut& #2\cr
    \omit&\hrulefill&\omit\hrulefill\cr
    #1&\strut&\cr}
}}
\def\bxx{
  \bx{113}{114} & 
  \bx{99}{100} & 
  \bx{84}{92} & 
  \bx{97}{101}\cr
  \noalign{\hrule}
}

{\offinterlineskip
\halign{\vrule\strut \hfill #\uv & #\uv & #\uv & #\uv\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
\bxx\bxx\bxx
}}\bye
```

[image]

Comment: TeXnicians: this is the first table I've ever created in Plain TeX; please go easy on me if I've committed any cardinal sins!

Comment: Doing it the hard way again ;-) (+1)

Comment: +1 I added a second plain TeX solution here. We can see, that plain TeX solutions are more simple than LaTeX. The reason is that LaTeX doesn't give any help to user, it only does things more complicated.

Comment: I'm really liking these solutions. Have to agree that the plain tex is more simple, at least to a new comer like me. But since I have to do a bunch of tables, I can try a bunch of solutions!

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is no such package, but it can be achieved with basic setups, using `\multicolumn` and `\cline` macros.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}


\large
\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{L{1cm}|}}
\hline
& 114 & & 100 & & 92 & & 101  \tabularnewline
& & & & & & &   \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-8} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}\tabularnewline 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{113} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{84} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{97}  \tabularnewline
\hline
& 114 & & 100 & & 92 & & 101  \tabularnewline
& & & & & & &   \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-8} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}\tabularnewline 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{113} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{84} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{97}  \tabularnewline
\hline
& 114 & & 100 & & 92 & & 101  \tabularnewline
& & & & & & &   \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-8} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}\tabularnewline 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{113} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{84} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{97}  \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

% Now with booktabs features 

\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{L{0.5cm}|}}
\toprule
& 114 & & 100 & & 92 & & 101  \tabularnewline
&  & &  & &  & &   \tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{4-4} \cmidrule{6-6} \cmidrule{8-8} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}\tabularnewline 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{113} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{84} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{97}  \tabularnewline
\hline
& 114 & & 100 & & 92 & & 101  \tabularnewline
&  & &  & &  & &   \tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{4-4} \cmidrule{6-6} \cmidrule{8-8} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}\tabularnewline 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{113} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{84} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{97}  \tabularnewline
\hline
& 114 & & 100 & & 92 & & 101  \tabularnewline
&  & &  & &  & &   \tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{4-4} \cmidrule{6-6} \cmidrule{8-8} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}\tabularnewline 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{113} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{99} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{84} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{97}  \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\normalsize
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `booktabs` (lower one) version is better, in my point of view

Comment: Why do you think the lower one is better? To me the above one is definitely better (at least the lines are together).

Comment: @Manuel: A personal impression. It's quite difficult to tell

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, this effect is relatively easy to achieve in ConTeXt. Note the very clean separation of content and presentation.

```
\startsetups[cellular]
  \setupTABLE[frame=off, align={middle,lohi}, offset=0.5em]
  \setupTABLE[even] [odd][frame=on, offset=0.25em]
  \setupTABLE[even][even][rightframe=on, bottomframe=on]
  \setupTABLE[odd] [even][leftframe=on,  bottomframe=on]
  \setupTABLE[odd]  [odd][leftframe=on,  topframe=on]
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startTABLE[setups=cellular]
   \NC     \NC 114 \NC    \NC 100 \NC    \NC 92 \NC    \NC 101 \NC \NR
   \NC 113 \NC     \NC 99 \NC     \NC 84 \NC    \NC 97 \NC     \NC \NR
   \NC     \NC 114 \NC    \NC 100 \NC    \NC 92 \NC    \NC 101 \NC \NR
   \NC 113 \NC     \NC 99 \NC     \NC 84 \NC    \NC 97 \NC     \NC \NR
   \NC     \NC 114 \NC    \NC 100 \NC    \NC 92 \NC    \NC 101 \NC \NR
   \NC 113 \NC     \NC 99 \NC     \NC 84 \NC    \NC 97 \NC     \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{/bowlinggrid/.cd,
  box width/.store in=\bgridlargewidth,box width=3cm,
  box height/.store in=\bgridlargeheight,box height=2.5cm,
  small width/.store in=\bgridsmallwidth,small width=1.2cm,
  small height/.store in=\bgridsmallheight,small height=1cm,
  columns/.store in=\bgridcolnumber,columns=4} % I cannot get /.initial= to work
\newcommand*\bowlinggrind[2][]
  {%
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \tikzset{/bowlinggrid/.cd,#1}
   \foreach \N/\n [count=\cnt] in {#2}
     {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\currcolnumber{int(mod(\cnt-1,\bgridcolnumber))}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\currrownumber{int(ceil(\cnt/\bgridcolnumber))}
      \draw
       ({\currcolnumber*\bgridlargewidth},{-\currrownumber*\bgridlargeheight})
        node [above right] {\N}
        rectangle ++(\bgridlargewidth,\bgridlargeheight)
        rectangle ++(-\bgridsmallwidth,-\bgridsmallheight)
        node [above right] {\n};
     }
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\bowlinggrind
  {113/114,99/100,84/92,97/101,
   113/114,99/100,84/92,97/101,
   113/114,99/100,84/92,97/101,
   113/114,99/100,84/92,97/101}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\bowlinggrind[box width=1.8cm,box height=1.3cm,small width=.9cm,small height=.5cm]
  {113/114,99/100,84/92,97/101,
   113/114,99/100,84/92,97/101,
   113/114,99/100,84/92,97/101,
   113/114,99/100,84/92,97/101}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Paul Gessler wrote the Plain TeX solution using `\halign`. Great. I add another Plain TeX solution using only `\hbox` `\vbox`. The main idea is: if there are only fixed-size columns then we needn't to use `\halign`, but the `\hbox to` construction is sufficient.

```
\def\bx#1#2{\vbox{\hbox to4em{\hss\vbox{%
                      \hbox to2em{\strut\vrule\hfil#2\hfil}\hrule}}
                  \hbox to2em{\strut\hfil#1\hfil}}\vrule\ignorespaces
}
\def\bxx{\hbox{\vrule \bx{113}{114} \bx{99}{100} \bx{84}{92} \bx{97}{101} }%
         \hrule}

\vbox{\hrule \bxx \bxx \bxx}

\bye
```

Answer (score 4):

With standard LaTeX methods, also with a friendly syntax. The trick is to nest `tabular` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\blockwidth}
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\blockwidth}{0000}}

\newcommand{\block}[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c|c@{}}
  & \makebox[\blockwidth][r]{#2\enspace} \\
  \cline{2-2}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makebox[\blockwidth][r]{#1\enspace}}
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{@{}c@{}|}}
\hline
\block{113}{114} & \block{99}{100} & \block{84}{92} & \block{97}{101} \\
\hline
\block{113}{114} & \block{99}{100} & \block{84}{92} & \block{97}{101} \\
\hline
\block{113}{114} & \block{99}{100} & \block{84}{92} & \block{97}{101} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The shape of the blocks can be easily adapted if some more room is desired.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A free interpretation of the desired design that is not a table, so that  allow a flexible format.

> [image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\newcounter{cell}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\nestedcell#1{%
\noindent\fboxsep5pt\fboxrule1pt
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b][2cm]{\dimexpr.25\textwidth-12pt}
\hfill{\color{red}\vrule\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\centering\small\sffamily\arabic{cell}
\addtocounter{cell}{1}
\par\smallskip\hrule\end{minipage}}\par\vfill
\raggedright#1\vphantom{hp}\end{minipage}}\hspace{1.25pt}}

\def\nocell#1{%
\noindent\fboxsep6pt\fboxrule0pt
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b][2cm]{\dimexpr.25\textwidth-12pt}
\par\vfill
\raggedright#1\mbox{\vphantom{hp}}\end{minipage}}\hspace{1.25pt}}


\begin{document}
\nestedcell{101}% 
\nestedcell{}% cell with no content
\nestedcell{103}%
\nestedcell{104}%
\nestedcell{105}%
\nestedcell{106}%
\nocell{}%
\nestedcell{106}%
\nestedcell{107}\nestedcell{Some too long for a row}%
\nestedcell{108}\nestedcell{109}%
\nocell{I am still here}%
\nocell{}%
\nestedcell{}%
\nestedcell{Do not use more text than this.}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give an alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  rows = {2em}, rowsep = 4pt,
  columns = {2em}, colsep = 4pt,
  row{odd} = {h}, row{even} = {f}, % head and foot alignment
  hline{odd}, hline{even} = {even}{solid},
  vline{odd}, vline{even} = {odd}{solid},  
}
      & 114 &    & 100 &    & 92 &    & 101 \\
  113 &     & 99 &     & 84 &    & 97 &     \\ 
      & 114 &    & 100 &    & 92 &    & 101 \\
  113 &     & 99 &     & 84 &    & 97 &     \\ 
      & 114 &    & 100 &    & 92 &    & 101 \\
  113 &     & 99 &     & 84 &    & 97 &     \\ 
      & 114 &    & 100 &    & 92 &    & 101 \\
  113 &     & 99 &     & 84 &    & 97 &     \\ 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\UP}{\Block[borders={left,bottom}]{}{}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|cc|cc|cc|cc|}
\Hline
      & \UP 114 &    & \UP 100 &    & \UP 92 &    & \UP 101 \\
  113 &         & 99 &         & 84 &        & 97 &         \\ 
\Hline
      & \UP 114 &    & \UP 100 &    & \UP 92 &    & \UP 101 \\
  113 &         & 99 &         & 84 &        & 97 &         \\ 
\Hline
      & \UP 114 &    & \UP 100 &    & \UP 92 &    & \UP 101 \\
  113 &         & 99 &         & 84 &        & 97 &         \\ 
\Hline
      & \UP 114 &    & \UP 100 &    & \UP 92 &    & \UP 101 \\
  113 &         & 99 &         & 84 &        & 97 &         \\
\Hline 
\end{NiceTabular}
 
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]